# how to parse this string in scheme?

Tags: regex, scheme, racket

I have a string that looks like this

```
"21 4\n21 2 _ _ 19 11\n 12 _ _ 1 _ _\n_ _ _ 7 13 _"
```

(there is a blank space between 21 and 4, 21 and 2, 2 and _, etc)

I would like to loop through it, extract each number, character _ or \n.

(basically split the string on the blank spaces and on the \n)

Using substring will not work because some elements have more than one character (like 21 or 13)

If the easiest way would be to convert the string into a list like

```
["21" "4" "\n" "21" "2" "_" "_" "19" "11" "\n"...]
```

that would be fine but not sure how to do it.

Comment: Are `"` included in string ?

Comment: No. Just integers, spaces and \n.

Comment: I don't know `scheme` and `racket` so I just gave you the regex. I hope you can do rest of the programming.

Comment: Thank you for the regex.

Comment: On this site gratitude should be paid by either up voting or by accepting the appropriate solution. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is something to get you started. This does not use regular expressions - just repeated use of `read`.

```
#lang racket

(define (parse-line line)
  (define in (open-input-string line))
  (for/list ([sym (in-port read in)])
    (~a sym)))

(define (parse str)
  (define in (open-input-string str))
  (for/list ([line (in-lines in)])
    (parse-line line)))


(parse "21 4\n21 2 _ _ 19 11\n 12 _ _ 1 _ _\n_ _ _ 7 13 _")
```

The output is:

```
'(("21" "4") 
  ("21" "2" "_" "_" "19" "11") 
  ("12" "_" "_" "1" "_" "_") 
  ("_" "_" "_" "7" "13" "_"))
```

Comment: Thank you this is a nice way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Well the regex to split your string will be

**Regex**: `/[\d]+|_|\\n/g`

**Explanation**:

`[\d]+` searches for digits.

`_` searches for underscore.

`\\n` searches for `\n`. Needed to escape double times for `\`.

`|` is the **OR** condition. Either of the three.

`g` to allow global search.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lA1xF2/1)